# why One-Hot Encoder can avoid the situation that the model will misunderstand the data to be in some kind of order if the data has been Label Encoding

Tags: machine-learning, data, data-analysis, encoding

We know that we prefer to using **One-Hot Encoding** not **Label Encoding** when processing with non-ordinal data.
 
And I real a [blog](https://medium.com/@contactsunny/label-encoder-vs-one-hot-encoder-in-machine-learning-3fc273365621) which give the difference between **Label Encoding** and **One-Hot Encoding**.
So I am wondering why **One-Hot Encoder** can avoid the situation that the model will misunderstand the data to be in some kind of order, $0 < 1 < 2$ if the data has been **Label Encoding**.
Does it have some provements and theories?
Or anyone just can explain it in intuition.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest I haven't seen any difference

Answer (score 1):

From the blog, one hot encoding resolves the issue by explicitly showing that 1 category is true, while all others are false (1 vs 0). One column is turned into 3 columns which describe all categories as either true or false.

As opposed to letting a model see one column with 0, 1, and 2. One column to show this data with label encoding does make it seem as if the data is numerical so 0 < 1 < 2.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

This might help:

Let's say you have three countries: USA, Germany, and China. No ranking.

Label Encoding turns the countries into numbers.

**For example, 1 (USA),2 (Germany), and 3 (China).**

If you don't One Hot Encode, **the theory states** (source: Sebastian Raschka "Machine Learning with Python"), that **you create ordinalit**y.

In other words, USA is better than Germany and Germany is better than China.

As you have no ranking (order), you don't want that. Thus, we One Hot Encode.

Personally, I have tested this several times and only Label Encoded (not ranking features) **with Logistic Regression and have NOT seen a difference**. But I've only done it a few times. And, if an ML expert like Sebastian Raschka says we should One Hot Encode for non-ordinal numerical data than I trust him.